# How can I improve the cancelSale or depositEarnest functions to guard against DoS attack scenario where an attacker could call cancelSale & get ETH?

Tags: solidity, dos

I have tried onlyBuyerSeller modifiers and refund distribution solutions in the cancelSale function to guard against attacker calling cancelSale function. In testing, attacker can still get the ETH.

Here is the contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC721 {
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _id
    ) external;
}

contract Escrow {
    address public nftAddress;
    address payable public seller;
    address public inspector;
    address public lender;
    address public lawyer;

    modifier onlyBuyer(uint256 _nftID) {
        require(msg.sender == buyer[_nftID], "Escrow: Only buyer can call this method");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlySeller() {
        require(msg.sender == seller, "Escrow: Only seller can call this method");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyInspector() {
        require(msg.sender == inspector, "Escrow: Only inspector can call this method");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyLawyer() {
        require(msg.sender == lawyer, "Escrow: Only lawyer can call this method");
        _;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => bool) public isListed;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public purchasePrice;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public escrowAmount;
    mapping(uint256 => address) public buyer;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public inspectionPassed;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public legalPassed;
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool)) public approval;

    event SaleFinalized(uint256 indexed nftID, address indexed buyer, address indexed seller, uint256 salePrice);

    constructor(
        address _nftAddress,
        address payable _seller,
        address _inspector,
        address _lender,
        address _lawyer
    ) {
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;
        seller = _seller;
        inspector = _inspector;
        lender = _lender;
        lawyer = _lawyer;
    }

    function list(
        uint256 _nftID,
        address _buyer,
        uint256 _purchasePrice,
        uint256 _escrowAmount
      
    ) public payable onlySeller {
        // Transfer NFT from seller to this contract
        IERC721(nftAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _nftID);

        isListed[_nftID] = true;
        purchasePrice[_nftID] = _purchasePrice;
        escrowAmount[_nftID] = _escrowAmount;
        buyer[_nftID] = _buyer;
      
    }

    // Put Under Contract (only buyer - payable escrow)
    function depositEarnest(uint256 _nftID) public payable onlyBuyer(_nftID) {
        require(msg.value == escrowAmount[_nftID], "Escrow: Deposit must be equal to escrow amount");
    }

    // Update Inspection Status (only inspector)
    function updateInspectionStatus(uint256 _nftID, bool _passed)
        public
        onlyInspector
    {
        inspectionPassed[_nftID] = _passed;
    }

    function updateLegalStatus(uint256 _nftID, bool _passed)
        public
        onlyLawyer
    {
        legalPassed[_nftID] = _passed;
    }

    // Approve Sale
    function approveSale(uint256 _nftID) public {
        approval[_nftID][msg.sender] = true;
    }

    // Finalize Sale
    // -> Require inspection status (add more items here, like appraisal)
    // -> Require sale to be authorized
    // -> Require funds to be correct amount
    // -> Transfer NFT to buyer
    // -> Transfer Funds to Seller

    bool private locked;

    modifier noReentrant() {
        require(!locked, "Escrow: Reentrant call detected");
        locked = true;
        _;
        locked = false;
    }
    
    // Finalize Sale
    function finalizeSale(uint256 _nftID) public noReentrant {
        // Check
        require(inspectionPassed[_nftID], "Escrow: Inspection not passed");
        require(legalPassed[_nftID], "Escrow: Legal check not passed");
        require(approval[_nftID][buyer[_nftID]], "Escrow: Buyer has not approved the sale");
        require(approval[_nftID][seller], "Escrow: Seller has not approved the sale");
        require(approval[_nftID][lender], "Escrow: Lender has not approved the sale");
        uint256 price = purchasePrice[_nftID];
        require(address(this).balance >= price, "Escrow: Contract does not have enough balance");

        // Effects
        isListed[_nftID] = false;
        purchasePrice[_nftID] = 0; // Resetting the purchase price
        escrowAmount[_nftID] = 0; // Resetting the escrow amount

        // Interactions
        (bool success, ) = payable(seller).call{value: price}("");
        require(success, "Transfer to seller failed");

        IERC721(nftAddress).transferFrom(address(this), buyer[_nftID], _nftID);

        emit SaleFinalized(_nftID, buyer[_nftID], seller, price);
    }

    modifier onlyBuyerOrSeller(uint256 _nftID) {
        require(
            msg.sender == buyer[_nftID] || msg.sender == seller,
            "Escrow: Only buyer or seller can call this method"
        );
        _;
    }

    function cancelSale(uint256 _nftID) public onlyBuyerOrSeller(_nftID) {
        require(isListed[_nftID], "Escrow: NFT not listed");
        
        address buyerAddress = buyer[_nftID];
        uint256 refundAmount = escrowAmount[_nftID];

        // Reset the listing status and amounts to prevent reentrancy
        isListed[_nftID] = false;
        buyer[_nftID] = address(0); // Reset buyer address
        escrowAmount[_nftID] = 0;
        purchasePrice[_nftID] = 0;

        if (!inspectionPassed[_nftID]) {
            require(msg.sender == buyerAddress, "Escrow: Only specific buyer can cancel before inspection");
            require(address(this).balance >= refundAmount, "Escrow: Insufficient balance for refund");

            // Refund the earnest money to the specific buyer
            (bool refundSuccess, ) = payable(buyerAddress).call{value: refundAmount}("");
            require(refundSuccess, "Escrow: Refund to buyer failed");
        } else {
            require(msg.sender == seller, "Escrow: Only seller can cancel after inspection");
            require(address(this).balance >= refundAmount, "Escrow: Insufficient balance for sale");

            // Transfer the sale amount to the seller
            (bool saleSuccess, ) = payable(seller).call{value: refundAmount}("");
            require(saleSuccess, "Escrow: Transfer to seller failed");
        }
    }

    function resetListing(uint256 _nftID) private {
        isListed[_nftID] = false;
        buyer[_nftID] = address(0); // Reset buyer address
        escrowAmount[_nftID] = 0;
        purchasePrice[_nftID] = 0;
    }


    receive() external payable {}

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Here is the test suite:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

const tokens = (n) => {
    return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), 'ether')
}

describe('Escrow', () => {
    let buyer, seller, inspector, lender, lawyer, attacker
    let realEstate, escrow

    beforeEach(async () => {
        // Setup accounts
        [buyer, seller, inspector, lender, lawyer, attacker] = await ethers.getSigners()

        // Deploy Real Estate
        const RealEstate = await ethers.getContractFactory('RealEstate')
        realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy()

        // Mint 
        let transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).mint("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTudSYeM7mz3PkYEWXWqPjomRPHogcMFSq7XAvsvsgAPS")
        await transaction.wait()

        // Deploy Escrow
        const Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory('Escrow')
        escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
            realEstate.address,
            seller.address,
            inspector.address,
            lender.address,
            lawyer.address,
        )

        // Approve Property
        transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.address, 1)
        await transaction.wait()

        // List Property
        transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).list(1, buyer.address, tokens(10), tokens(5))
        await transaction.wait()
    })        

    describe('Deployment', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            it('Returns NFT address', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.nftAddress()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(realEstate.address)
            })

            it('Returns seller', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.seller()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(seller.address)
            })

            it('Returns inspector', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.inspector()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(inspector.address)
            })

            it('Returns lender', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.lender()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(lender.address)

                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })

            it('Returns lawyer', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.lawyer()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(lawyer.address)

                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })  
        })
    })

    describe('Listing', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            it('Updates as listed', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.isListed(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(true)
            })

            it('Returns buyer', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.buyer(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(buyer.address)
            })

            it('Returns purchase price', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.purchasePrice(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(tokens(10))
            })

            it('Returns escrow amount', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.escrowAmount(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(tokens(5))
            })

            it('Updates ownership', async () => {
                expect(await realEstate.ownerOf(1)).to.be.equal(escrow.address)
                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })
        })
          
        describe('Failure', async () => {
            let nftAddress

            it("Should fail when a non-seller tries to list an NFT", async function () {
            await expect(escrow.connect(attacker).list(1, seller.address, 1000, 200)).to.be.revertedWith("Escrow: Only seller can call this method");
            })
        })
    })
       
    describe('Deposits', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                const transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(1, { value: tokens(5) })
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates contract balance', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.getBalance()
                expect(result).to.be.equal(tokens(5))

                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })
        })
         
    
        describe('Failure', async () => {

            it("Should fail when a non-buyer tries to deposit earnest money", async function () {
                await expect(escrow.connect(attacker).depositEarnest(1, { value: 200 })).to.be.revertedWith("Escrow: Only buyer can call this method");
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Inspection', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                const transaction = await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates inspection status', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.inspectionPassed(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(true)
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Approval', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lender).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates approval status', async () => {
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, buyer.address)).to.be.equal(true)
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, seller.address)).to.be.equal(true)
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, lender.address)).to.be.equal(true)

                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })
        })

        describe('Failure', async () => {

           it("Should fail when a non-inspector tries to update inspection status", async function () {               
                await expect(escrow.connect(attacker).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)).to.be.revertedWith("Escrow: Only inspector can call this method");
            })
        })
    })


    describe('Legal', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                const transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).updateLegalStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates legal status', async () => {
                const result = await escrow.legalPassed(1)
                expect(result).to.be.equal(true)
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Approval', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lender).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates approval status', async () => {
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, buyer.address)).to.be.equal(true)
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, seller.address)).to.be.equal(true)
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, lender.address)).to.be.equal(true)
                expect(await escrow.approval(1, lawyer.address)).to.be.equal(true)

                const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)
            })
        })

        describe('Failure', async () => {
           it("Should fail when a non-lawyer tries to update legal status", async function () {
                
                await expect(escrow.connect(attacker).updateLegalStatus(1, true)).to.be.revertedWith("Escrow: Only lawyer can call this method");
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Sale', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {

            beforeEach(async () => {
                let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(1, { value: tokens(5) })
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).updateLegalStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lender).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                await lender.sendTransaction({ to: escrow.address, value: tokens(5) })

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).finalizeSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Updates ownership', async () => {
                expect(await realEstate.ownerOf(1)).to.be.equal(buyer.address)
            })

            it('Updates balance', async () => {
                expect(await escrow.getBalance()).to.be.equal(0)
            })
        })

        describe('Failure', async () => {
            beforeEach(async () => {

            let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(1, { value: tokens(5) })
            await transaction.wait()

            transaction = await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)
            await transaction.wait()

            transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).updateLegalStatus(1, false)
            await transaction.wait()            

            })

            it('Fails to update ownership due to unmet condition', async () => {

            await expect(escrow.connect(seller).finalizeSale(1)).to.be.reverted

            const currentOwner = await realEstate.ownerOf(1)

            expect(await realEstate.ownerOf(1)).to.not.equal(buyer.address)
            })

            it('Fails to transfer escrow to seller due to sale not finaized', async () => {
                
            const result = await escrow.getBalance();
            expect(result).to.not.equal(0)
            })             
        })
    })

    describe('Finalize Sale', () => {
        describe('Success', () => {
            let nftID, purchasePrice

            beforeEach(async () => {
                purchasePrice = tokens(10)
                nftID = 1

                await lender.sendTransaction({ to: escrow.address, value: purchasePrice })

                let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(1, { value: tokens(5) })
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).updateLegalStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lender).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()                

            })

            it('Should finalize sale and emit event', async () => {
                await expect(escrow.finalizeSale(nftID)).to.emit(escrow, "SaleFinalized") 
                .withArgs(nftID, buyer.address, seller.address, purchasePrice);
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Cancellation', async () => {
        describe('Success', () => {
            let nftID

            beforeEach(async () => {
                nftID = 1 

                let transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(1, { value: tokens(5) })
                await transaction.wait()
            })

            it('Returns balance to buyer if inspection not passed', async () => {
                // Update Inspection Status to fail
                await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(nftID, false)

                // Record initial buyer balance
                const initialBuyerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(buyer.address)

                // Perform Cancellation
                await escrow.connect(buyer).cancelSale(nftID)

                // Check final buyer balance
                const finalBuyerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(buyer.address)
                expect(finalBuyerBalance).to.be.greaterThan(initialBuyerBalance)
            })

            it('Sends balance to seller if inspection passed', async () => {
                // Update Inspection Status to pass
                await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(nftID, true)

                // Record initial seller balance
                const initialSellerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(seller.address)

                // Perform Cancellation
                await escrow.connect(seller).cancelSale(nftID)

                // Check final seller balance
                const finalSellerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(seller.address);
                expect(finalSellerBalance).to.be.greaterThan(initialSellerBalance);
            })
        })       

    describe('DoS Attack on cancelSale', () => {
        let nftID1, nftID2, purchasePrice

            beforeEach(async () => {
                nftID1 = 1
                nftID2 = 2
                purchasePrice = tokens(10)

                // Ensure the seller owns the NFTs
                await realEstate.connect(seller).mint(nftID1)
                await realEstate.connect(seller).mint(nftID2)

                // Then check ownership
                const ownerOfNFT1 = await realEstate.ownerOf(nftID1)
                const ownerOfNFT2 = await realEstate.ownerOf(nftID2)
                // Ensure that the seller is the owner before approving
                if (ownerOfNFT1 === seller.address) {
                    await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.address, nftID1)                        
                }

                if (ownerOfNFT2 === seller.address) {
                    await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.address, nftID2)
                }
                
                // Seller lists house 2 for buyer 2
                await escrow.connect(seller).list(nftID2, attacker.address, purchasePrice, tokens(1))

                 //Buyer 1 sends depositEarnest of 5 ETH to the contract
                await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(nftID1, { value: tokens(5) })
                /*await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(nftID2, { value: tokens(5) })*/


            })

            it('Incorrectly sends 1 ETH to buyer 2 on cancelSale without deposit', async () => {
                const initialAttackerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(attacker.address)

                // Buyer 2 decides to cancelSale
                await escrow.connect(attacker).cancelSale(nftID2)

                const finalAttackerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(attacker.address)

                // Check if attacker (buyer 2) received 1 ETH without depositing
                expect(finalAttackerBalance).to.be.greaterThan(initialAttackerBalance)
            })

            it("Seller can't finalizeSale due to insufficient contract balance", async () => {
                // Buyer 2 cancels sale, erroneously draining the contract
                await escrow.connect(attacker).cancelSale(nftID2);

                transaction = await escrow.connect(inspector).updateInspectionStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lawyer).updateLegalStatus(1, true)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(buyer).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                transaction = await escrow.connect(lender).approveSale(1)
                await transaction.wait()

                // Attempt to finalize sale
                await expect(escrow.connect(seller).finalizeSale(nftID1)).to.be.revertedWith("Escrow: Contract does not have enough balance")
            })
        })
    })
})
```